# How to combine multiple reference table data to json?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

example:https://rextester.com/CVYPI14438
I got four tables.
The table1 is a reference table for mapping tablename and col.
Table0 is serial table.
Tab77 and roc99 are raw data tables.

```
table0
    serial
1   a22
2   a33
3   a11


table1
    name    tablename   col
1   weight  tab77       e04
2   height  roc99       e09
3   tel     tab77       h04


tab77
    serial  e04 h04
1   a22     69  9998776
2   a33     50  6668676
3   a11     66  7328989
4   a44     66  7888989


roc99
        serial  e09
    1   a11     176
    2   a33     182
    3   a22     166
    4   a88     192
```

I wnat to make the result like this.

```
    serial  raw
1   a22     {"tel": "9998776", "height": "166", "weight": "69"}
2   a33     {"tel": "6668676", "height": "182", "weight": "50"}
3   a11     {"tel": "7328989", "height": "176", "weight": "66"}
```

I can't type the tablename and col one by one.
Is it possible to get this result automatically with sql only?
Why the table relation designed like this?
How to call this table relation structure?

Comment: That is a really strange data model.

Comment: What if there are multiple rows for the same serial e.g. in roc99?

Comment: You cannot really do this in SQL.  Dynamic table names are not supported.  You can do this with some very complicated dynamic SQL, but you should fix the data model.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm trying to fix the data model with this query.

Answer (score 0):

This code will give an out put equivalent to your results,

```
SELECT t1.serial,concat('{','"tel": "',max(h04),'", "height": "',max(e09),'", "weight": "',max(e04),'"}') as raw FROM 
tab77 t1
INNER JOIN roc99 t2 on t1.serial=t2.serial
group by t1.serial ;
```

You can try this dynamic query here I'm unpivoting your table and doing string agg, with in the array you need to include the column list.

```
SELECT serial,concat('{',string_agg(val,', '),'}') as raw
from
(select serial, concat('"',cat,'": "',val,'"') as val
from(select t1.serial,
unnest(array['tel', 'height', 'weight']) AS cat,
       unnest(array[h04, e09, e04]) AS val
 from tab77 t1
INNER JOIN roc99 t2 on t1.serial=t2.serial
order by t1.serial)a)b group by serial ;
```

Comment: Thanks.However, you type the name and map the name to the column manually in this query. This doesn't help much.

Comment: Do you have more columns

Comment: So you require a dynamic query, let me have a look